# What is proxy graph?

Tags: algorithms, graphing-functions

Is there any data structure called Proxy Graph which has practical implementation? I tried to search for it but didn't any sources, so I want to know if any such data structure or concept exists.

Comment: Where did you find this term? My guess is that this term lacks a universally accepted meaning, so please give us additional context. (Also the question is incomplete.)

Comment: Sir we are given a presentation topic regarding proxy graph and its algorithm and complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you understand the word "Proxy", you may have a clue about "Proxy Graph".

First, let me clear your confusion. Proxy Graph is not a data structure, although you might have a Graph data structure to represent, store and implement Proxy Graph.

When dealing with large "Topographic Maps", the proxy graph contact model approximates by using the "proxy location to vertices and edges".  If you are dealing with computational models, you may have to look for optimal data structures for graphs and that might depend on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: http://www.docstoc.com/docs/108086520/Data-Structures-and-algorithms-(IS-ZC361)-Graph-Traversals-      Found here more reference about proxy graph and graphs related to it.    Tks for the answer.